# using vue.set in vuex is not updating the state

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to add an object into a nested array, and it is not working, but I've used this for other states and it works fine.

Has it got something to do with it begin a nested array?

this is the code I'm using

```
Vue.set(state.sections[getCurrentSection(state).index].rows[getCurrentRow(state).index].columns[getCurrentColumn(state).index].elements, 0, element)
```

this is the element object

```
var element = {
    id: id,
    style: {
        backgroundColor: {
            value: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)',
        },
    },
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: yeah its because you are using a nested array. Vue can't detect the change to that index of `state.sections`

Comment: really?!? is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Without being able to see any of your vuex module, my advice would be to change your data model from a nested array

Comment: fixed it, i just needed to updated all the nested objects so they were up to date :)

Comment: ok, that sounds like a pretty round-about way of doing it, but if you're happy I'm happy

Comment: yeah, i might change the data model ha

Comment: `state.sections[getCurrentSection(state).index].rows[getCurrentRow(state).index].columns[getCurrentColumn(state).index]` Wut.

Comment: Time to a feedback?

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

Another option to clone:

```js
function hasProp(arg1, arg2) {
  return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(arg1, arg2);
}

function extend(arg1, arg2) {
  const keys = Object.keys(arg2);
  const len = keys.length;

  let i = 0;

  while (i < len) {
    arg1[keys[i]] = arg2[keys[i]];
    i += 1;
  }

  if (hasProp(arg2, 'toString')) {
    arg1.toString = arg2.toString;
  }

  if (hasProp(arg2, 'valueOf')) {
    arg1.valueOf = arg2.valueOf;
  }

  return arg1;
}

const obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: { a: 1, b: 2}
};

const cloned = extend({}, obj1);
cloned.a = 9999;

console.log(obj1, cloned);
```

---

1. Make a [deep copy](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/f84da3005454e8ea4075a6820bcf69efaabe81cb/src/util.js) of your `state.sections`;
2. Create a new `object` and make your modifications on it;
3. Replace `state.sections` with you new object - `state.sections = Object.assign({}, newObject)`.

Your `state` and your view updated.